# Unablee toexport trained model from AutoML vision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-automl

I trained a model using google AutoML Vision and now I want to export it to use it locally, I tried [this](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/model-export#export) tutorial from Google official doc with no success.

Actually, in model list, when I click the three dots (more actions) there is no export option:
[image]

Even in the test & use page there is no option to export the model:
[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hey, could you please let us know how was the model trained? Did you follow a tutorial? Please share it

Comment: @KevinQuinzel I started by searching for some information on Google. Mainly, I followed Google Cloud Console interface, it's quite clear to use, then when I face some ambiguities I do some searches to handle them. If you are not familiar with Google Cloud Console or you simply want a structured explanation this link would be interesting for you:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/how-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/model-export#export) you are following is for AutoML tables and, although similar, is not exactly the same as for AutoML Vision.

For AutoML Vision you can train two types of models, [Cloud hosted](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/train) and [Edge-exportable](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/train-edge). As the name may infer, only the second ones can be exported.
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/export-edge) you can see the documentation for exporting AutoML Vision Edge models.

My assumption is you have trained a Cloud hosted model which is not exportable.

There is currently a feature request opened to allow this behavior. You can find it [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/113122585). If you would also be interested on it you can star it to keep updated about the progress.